# Wireshark unable to capture layer 3

Tags: wireshark

I'm new to Wireshark. I'm trying to visit google.com and capture the packets. However, Wireshark is only showing me layer 2 packets as shown below: 
[image: Here's the screenshot of that]

Hence, filters like `ip` and `ip addr == x.x.x.x` are not showing anything.

I want to see layer 3 packets as well. How can I do this?

Comment: This is not a security question but a Wireshark use question. You also do not describe how you configured the capture or what interface you intended to capture or what interface you are using to browse.

Comment: @schroeder that makes sense, would you like me to delete this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have chosen the right interface (but "en0" looks reasonable) I'd say you seem to be in "monitor mode". Try and disable this at

```
Edit / Preferences / User Interface / Capture / Interfaces: / Edit / Device: en1 [x] Monitor Mode
```

Monitor Mode is needed if you want to capture traffic which does not originate from or terminate at the machine you are running your capture on. But from you question I learn that you want to capture the traffic you are creating yourself when connecting to Google.

For background information on this subject, have a look at https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/WLAN.

Comment: Thanks! That worked like a charm. Since I'm using a Mac, I had to go through Capture > Options, in the input tab scroll right and disable the monitor checkbox.